# Kronecker product of diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to figure out how one would come up with a case for [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) of diagonal matrices. Suppose we have a $2\times 2$ matrices
$$M_i = \begin{bmatrix}
a_i && 0\\
0 && b_i
\end{bmatrix}.$$
I want to figure out
$$M = \bigotimes_{i=1}^n M_i.$$
What would the diagonal elements of matrix $M$ would be?

Comment: They're enumerated in a way similar to the way binary counts up - if you write out the case $n=3$, you may be able to see the pattern

Comment: Yeah, i wrote down up to 4 and saw some patterns but I got stuck generalising it

Comment: Math questions with no physics context should be posted on Math SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the binary expansion of $k$, which I'll write as $k_1k_2\dotsb k_n$, where each $k_i\in\{0,1\}$ is a binary digit. Then, the $k^{\text{th}}$ diagonal element (zero-indexed) of $M$ is a product of $n$ terms, where the $i^{\text{th}}$ term is $a_i$ if $k_i=0$, and $b_i$ if $k_i=1$. So, essentially, the diagonal elements of $M$ are ordered in an analogous way to the  way that binary counts up.

As a concrete example, consider the case $n=4$. Then, the diagonal elements of $M$, in order, are:
$$a_1a_2a_3a_4,a_1a_2a_3b_4,a_1a_2b_3a_4,\dotsc,b_1b_2a_3b_4,b_1b_2b_3a_4,b_1b_2b_3b_4$$
Meanwhile, the binary numbers from $0$ to $2^4-1$, inculsive, are:
$$0000,0001,0010,\dotsc,1101,1110,1111$$
Hopefully you can see the bijection between the sets.